# How to give some spaces for nextline in android textview?

Tags: android, textview, text-formatting

In my application I have a quiz page..

It have questions and answer.. Each question have question number..

Sample question:

> 1. Which one of the following would make a suitable inert electrode in
>
> the electrolysis of sodium sulfate solution?

But I want to give some space for next line to align properly..

> 1. Which one of the following would make a suitable inert electrode in
>
>    the electrolysis of sodium sulfate solution?

Currently I acheive with two textviews (one for number another for question) within linearlayout.

My question:

**This alignment possible with same textview?**

Comment: could you provide the xml and java for layout and text setting?

Comment: Are u picking these strings from strings.xml?

Comment: @RanjithKumar Use &#160; for each space for that string in your strings.xml and try

Comment: @nandsito I done with one linearlayout & two childs(qtn number & question).. similar to Ak9637 answer...

Comment: @Raghavendra the problem is I can`t determine the second line.. because  each device have different width.. So I can`t fix the which is next line..

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `android:gravity="center"`. This might look better.
On applying it, the text would be looking like

```
  Q1: This will be the line of your question and 
           this will be the second line.
```

Comment: See the thing that you are asking can't be done with the single textview. Just because you asked for the single textview then it's better to go for the gravity.

Comment: okee.. If I give gravity center --> how the second line add some space?

My question (How to give some spaces for nextline...)

Comment: If you apply gravity then your text (upper line and below line) both will come to the center of the screen. Just because the upper line would be filled completely, the next line will automatically come in the middle. Let me edit the answer to show this in effect.

Comment: Just see the padding automatically added by the gravity in the second line.

Comment: ohh sry...now understand.. Your answer also good one.. but I want left align only...

Comment: Although this might not be the best solution but still it will work. Just use

Comment: it not suit for all questions.. incase if 3 line question.. 2nd line may be not aligned..

Comment: textsize in 'dp' and this will let you to see the same word starting and ending in all the devices. Then according to your need you can edit your strings.xml file to give the appropriate spaces and \n whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can use two textviews one for the number of the question and the other for the question and answer just seperate them with a "\n" 
or add tab space with "\t" before the answer , both should work ,
much luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can try **'\t'** it make space but in android text align based on device width.
For example:

```
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1.Which one of the following would make a
suitable inert electrode in \t \t \t the electrolysis of sodium sulfate solution?"/>
```